# Notation for Lie algebra Actions?

Tags: symbols

How can I do something like this:

[image]

This is to denote an action of G on H by means of D. I don't want the arrow to be too long.

Thanks.

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212477/chain-of-curly-arrows-above-and-underneath-each-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) proposes `\curvearrowright` from the `amssymb` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$g\stackrel{D}{\curvearrowright}h$

$g\overset{D}{\curvearrowright}h$ % requires amsmath
\end{document}
```

[image]